# API to get latest browser and Flash versions?

Tags: flash, browser

I'm looking for an web service that would provide me with the latest version numbers for the major web browsers as well as Adobe Flash?

fresh-browsers.com seemed to be the go to place for this before but has been abandoned.

Note that I am not doing this for feature detection but so that I can tell my users to upgrade their Flash or web browser, so Modernizr will not solve my problems.